# Convert javascript from single date exclusion to multiple dates

Tags: javascript, prestashop-1.6

With our limited knowledge we were able to exclude certain dates in a date delivery module based on weekday and time. See code below.

But now we want to exclude all Wednesdays and Saturdays in the next year if you select carrier 99. So multiple disabledDays.push(excldatum) being each Wednesday and Saturday for one year starting from today if this particular carrier is selected.

Can someone please help us how to write that code?

```
    var selected_carrier = parseInt($('.delivery_option_radio:checked').val());
    var weekdag = new Date().getDay();
    var uur = new Date().getHours();
    var vandaag = new Date();
    var morgen = new Date();
    morgen.setDate(vandaag.getDate() + 1);
    var exclmaand = morgen.getMonth() + 1;
    var excldag = morgen.getDate();
    var excldatum = exclmaand + "-" + excldag;

    // carrier is postnl
    if (selected_carrier == 99) {
        // weekdag 0 is zondag t/m 6 is zaterdag
        if (weekdag > -1 && weekdag < 5) {
            // na 23 uur
            if (uur >= 23) {
                disabledDays.push(excldatum);
            }
        }
    }

    if (selected_carrier == 99) {
        // weekdag 5 is vrijdag
        if (weekdag == 5) {
            // na 10 uur
            if (uur >= 10) {
                disabledDays.push(excldatum);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following piece of code might work for you. It gets all dates for the specified weekdaysToProcess for the next 365 days starting today. Eg. [3,6] for Wednesday and Saturday.

You can add any other filtering you like of course.

```
    function GetDatesForWeekdaysForNext365Days(weekdaysToProcess) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var foundDates = [];

        for (var day = 0; day < 365; day++) {
            var calculatedDate = new Date();
            calculatedDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + day);
            var calculatedWeekDay = calculatedDate.getDay();
            if (weekdaysToProcess.includes(calculatedWeekDay)) {
                foundDates.push(calculatedDate);
            }
        }
        return foundDates;
    }
```

The function can be called for carrier 99 like:
`disabledDays = GetDatesForWeekdaysForNext365Days([3,6]);`